# Gettext, PHP and Windows 2008

Tags: php, windows, gettext

I have a Windows 2008 server (installed in italian). It runs Zend Server CE 5.1, which is Apache2.2 and PHP 5.3.5.

I created this simple script:

```
putenv("LC_ALL=de_DE");
bindtextdomain('messages', './langs');
textdomain('messages');

echo _("Hello world");
```

The directories are:

```
/lang
    /it_IT
       /LC_MESSAGES
           /messages.mo
           /messages.po
    /de_DE
       /LC_MESSAGES
           /messages.mo
           /messages.po
```

What I get is the italian message, not the german one.
It seems that `putenv()` has no effect.
Please note that the language directory structure is correct, since the `it_IT` file is correctly loaded.

How can I load the german translation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all locales are supported on windows. Also [locale names are different on windows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) too. Supported [languages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf%28vs.71%29.aspx) and [regions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cdax410z%28vs.71%29.aspx) are listed on microsoft sites. If you're developing on windows machine and your production server is on linux i think you should consider using [Zend_Translate](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.html)

Comment: But it worked on PHP 5.2... By the way, with Zend_Translate there is no need to care about what the hell the server uses. Thank you!